# Counting xyz-graphs in $\mathbb{Z}_n^3$

Tags: graph-theory, upper-lower-bounds, hypergraphs

This is a followup question to: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/38462/lower-bound-on-the-largest-restrained-cubic-subset

How many distinct xyz-graphs exist in $\mathbb{Z}_n^3$? We denote this number as $C(n)$

This question may be seen as a generalization of counting simple cycles in $K_{n,n}$, via the hypergraph description of xyz-graphs given in the linked article. Unfortunately, moving to the hypergraph complicates things substantially, so at the moment I will only attempt a lower bound on the number. With that in mind, the problem reduces to solving for the number of "Hamiltonian" xyz-graphs, which in our generalization will be xyz-graphs (thought of as sets of hyper-edges) which touch every 2-edge in $K_{n,n,n}$ exactly twice. One example of such a Hamiltonian xyz-graph is provided in the linked question and at https://11011110.github.io/blog/2006/06/09/topology-of-xyz.html and is given by the set:

$\{(x,y,z) \ | \ x+y+z=0\} \ \cup \ \{(x,y,z) \ | \ x+y+z=1\}$

where addition is done mod n. Let the number of Hamiltonian xyz-graphs of $K_{n,n,n}$ be $H(n)$. Now we may simply look at how many copies of $K_{i,i,i}$ exist in $K_{n,n,n}$. This is simply ${n \choose i}^3$, which gives us the formula:

$
C(n) \geq \sum\limits_{i=2}^n {n \choose i}^3H(i)
$

Note that $H(n)= \frac{n!(n-1)!}{2}$ in the 2-dimensional case of $K_{n,n}$. It seems like we could use a similar strategy for the 3-dimensional case and end up with something along the lines of $\frac{n!^2(n-1)!^2}{4}$ which would lead to

$
C(n) \geq \frac{1}{4}\sum\limits_{i=2}^n \frac{(i-1)!}{i}(n)_i^3
$

However I'm fairly certain this number is far too large, so there must be a number of extra constraints when building these Hamiltonian cycles.